# How to go to another activity in Fragments | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Need to create a button to go to a new activity in Fragments. I tried with the following code but its not working, This is my code,

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment {

    Button mTextuserinfo;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user,container,false);

        mTextuserinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userinfo_user);
        mTextuserinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(UserFragment.this, userinformation.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please Add the error you got when start new activity ?

Comment: cannot resolve constructor intent

Comment: Use the @HotJava Answer It will work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Looks like you have got your answer. Next time make sure you post the error you are getting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your onClick.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), userinformation.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

Also define your button like this:

```
mTextuserinfo = view.findViewById(R.id.userinfo_user);
```

Comment: because you can't use findViewById directly in a fragment. Use view.findViewById(R.id.userinfo_user);

Comment: @Hashini_HW This is different Error. Accept this answer & put another one for this issue.